# Do @-comments arrive after removing the answer?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-answers

When I delete an answer of my own due to the fact that it is incorrect, which someone else pointed out in the comments section of my answer, I frequently reply to that user using the familiar `@user` confirming that they were right. After that, I remove my answer.

My question is: does that user, whom I addressed using `@user`, still gets (part of) my reply in his inbox, even though my answer is removed after a few seconds I replied to him/her?

Comment: Post deleted. Did you see the comment in your inbox?

Comment: @Anna, nope, the only new message was your _"Post deleted. Did you see the comment in your inbox?"_. Thanks for testing. Rebecca is right! :)

Comment: -1 for questioning whether Rebecca is right! Just kidding. *mostly*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  When a post is deleted, that will cause the comment to be deleted from the inbox the next time the inbox is updated.  There may be a small duration where the inbox notification will be visible if the user happens to be around right then, but that is just temporary until the inbox is refreshed.

Comment: Though of course, please feel free to test with Anna. (:

Comment: I should've waited 3 minutes for a definitive answer. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear, no harm in a demo! (:

Comment: Rebecca, thanks, as you can see, Anna's test proved you're right!

Comment: @BartKiers, *whew*! (;

Comment: this needs a bit of updating since mod comments are immune to this

Answer (score 12):

Let's find out. Comment on this answer. I'll respond and then delete it.

---

Conclusion: my response to Bart did not appear in his inbox after the post was deleted.

Comment: Testing, 1, 2, ...

Comment: @Bart ... 3. :)

Comment: @Bart No problem. :)